# Python Request Module - Displaying More Results

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm currently working on a learner project for webscraping
I've picked my site:

> https://www.game.co.uk/en/m/games/best-selling-games/best-selling-xbox-one-games/?merchname=MobileTopNav-_-XboxOne_Games-_-BestSellers#Page0

On this page, there is a button on the bottom that displays the list of the next 10 products there without this button being clicked it does not display the next batch of products however the URL does not change when the button is clicked.

I wanted to ask how I will solve this dilemma using requests module.

My code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.game.co.uk/en/m/games/best-selling-games/best-selling-xbox-one-games/?merchname=MobileTopNav-_-XboxOne_Games-_-BestSellers")
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product"})

for item in all:
    print(item.find({"h2": "productInfo"}).text.replace('\h2','').replace(" ", ""))
    print(item.find("span",{"class": "condition"}).text + "  " + item.find("span",{"class": "value"}).text )
    try:
        print(item.find_all("span",{"class": "condition"})[1].text + "  " + item.find_all("span",{"class": "value"})[1].text )
    except:
        print("No Preowned")
    print("  ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to get all the items available in that page. You can make use of chrome dev tools to retrieve [this url](https://www.game.co.uk/en/m/games/best-selling-games/best-selling-xbox-one-games/?merchname=MobileTopNav-_-XboxOne_Games-_-BestSellers&pageNumber=2&pageMode=true) in which there is an option for page number increment.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

page_link = "https://www.game.co.uk/en/m/games/best-selling-games/best-selling-xbox-one-games/?merchname=MobileTopNav-_-XboxOne_Games-_-BestSellers&pageNumber={}&pageMode=true"

page_no = 0

while True:
    page_no+=1
    res = requests.get(page_link.format(page_no))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    container = soup.select(".productInfo h2")
    if len(container)<=1:break 

    for content in container:
        print(content.text)
```

Output of the last few titles:

```
ARK Survival Evolved
Kingdom Come Deliverance Special Edition
Halo 5 Guardians
Sonic Forces
The Elder Scrolls Online: Summerset - Digital
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution it seems to work however why is it you're one is able to display all the items whilst my one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a webcrawler that supports javascript/jquery execution - i.e. [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) (it uses BoutifulSoup under the hood)
The problem you're facing is that the content you try to access gets created dynamically via javascript when the mentioned button is clicked. 
When you request the page the additional html elements you want to read from are not created so BoutifulSoup cant find them.
Using selenium you can click buttons/fill out forms and much more. You can also wait for the server to create the content you want to access.

The documentation of [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) should be self explaining...